# How to right align text and justify it? [Latex]

Tags: alignment, latex

I've spent a while trying to figure this out and haven't able to make it so far.

My question is, I have a document in Latex and I would like to change the alignment of a piece of text to the right and justify it too. What I have now can be seen in this picture.

[image]

For the image above, this is the code:

[image]

I would like to get something like this.

[image]

I am just starting out with Latex and I'm still taking some time to learn about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually what you want is:

- justified text
- in a smaller box shifted to the right of page

The way to do that is with a `minipage` environment. This allows to determine a box with a given size and to put text (or anything) in it.

Then it is possible to place the `minipage` at a given position of the page.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

and the result

[image]

The `minipage` is 50% of textwidth. Change that value as required.

`\hfill` does horizontal filling and pushes next element (ie the minipage) towards the right margin. To have a finer control on the position of the minipage, you can use `\hspace{6cm}(minipage)\\`. It will leave 6cm, insert the minipage box and ends the "line" (`\\`).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and solution. I have been struggling with this for a while. Your answer is right what I needed. I added it with a few adjustments to my project and it worked just fine.